# Android | Update RecyclerView Adapter on ViewHolder onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I expect my 'heart' icon to change when my ViewHolder item is clicked.
Fortunately, it does this. However, an issue arises as multiple items seems to replicate the button click.

What I mean is:
If I tap the heart on item number 1. Other items throughout the list replicate also change the heart.
Why is this happening and what is a potential fix? I am confused why this issue is occuring as I am referencing the ViewHolder item. Thus, shouldn't it only affect the item I am clicking?

**View Holder**

```
        fun bind(item: Location) {
            heart.setOnClickListener {
                item.fav = item.fav != true
                heart.setImageDrawable(
                when (item.fav) {
                    false -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_border_heart))
                    else -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_whole_heart))
                })

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onBindViewHolder you need to save list of fave in change item image base on that list otherwise it changes randomly as view recreates

```
     fun bind(item: Location) {

 heart.setImageDrawable(
                when (item.fav) {
                    false -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_border_heart))
                    else -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_whole_heart))
                })
            heart.setOnClickListener {
                item.fav = item.fav != true
                heart.setImageDrawable(
                when (item.fav) {
                    false -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_border_heart))
                    else -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_whole_heart))
                })

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check the view ID in the `onClick` method. You can set `onClick` directly on the views as below.

```
    class LocationViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {

private val actLoc: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.location_main)
private val genLoc: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.location_subtitle)
private val heart: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.heart)
private lateinit var item: Location

fun bind(item: Location) {
    this.item = item
    actLoc.setText(item.actualLocation)
    actLoc.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "${item.cords}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    genLoc.setText(item.genLocation)
    genLoc.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "${item.cords}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    heart.setOnClickListener {
        item.fav = item.fav != true
        heart.setImageDrawable(
            when (item.fav) {
                false -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_border_heart))
                else -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_whole_heart))
            })

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however, the same issue still persists due to the reuse of view holders

Answer (score 0):

> However, an issue arises as multiple items seems to replicate the
> button click.

it is because of the cell recycling mechanism

```
heart.setImageDrawable(
   when (item.fav) {
       false -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_border_heart))
       else -> (ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_whole_heart))
})
```

should be part of the bind function in the viewholder and not part of the onClick function. What I would expect is

- Click informs the viewmodel
- Viewmodel update the dataset
- Viewmodel informs the recyclerview

Comment: That was one of my thought patterns. However, I decided to scrap that idea as I had the ViewModel tied to the Adapter. Therefore, I wasn't able to access the ViewModel from the ViewHolder.

How would you allow connecting the ViewModel with other aspects of the recyclerview?

Comment: you could pass a lambda to the constructor of your adapter to enable the adapter -> activity -> viewmodel communication.